# Multiple upload images using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i have this file upload of images, and i want to do with a multiple images. Ive been searching in google and i found any no luck at all. I have this code `<input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple="" />` and in my controller here

```
        echo ("<pre>");
        print_r($_FILES);
        echo ("</pre>s");
        $name_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['photo']['size']);
        $ctr = 0;

        if ($_FILES){
        $files = $_FILES['photo'];
        foreach($_FILES['photo']['name'] as $key=>$value){

            $_FILES['photo']['name']= $files['name'][$ctr];
            $_FILES['photo']['type']    = $files['type'][$ctr];
            $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$ctr];
            $_FILES['photo']['error']       = $files['error'][$ctr];
            $_FILES['photo']['size']    = $files['size'][$ctr];  


             echo ("<pre> NEW >>> " . $ctr);
        print_r($_FILES);
        echo ("</pre>");
        $ctr++;
                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '2048';
                //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
                //$config['max_height']  = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();

            print_r($data);
            $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
            $names= implode(',', $name_array);
/*          $this->load->database();
            $db_data = array('id'=> NULL,
                             'name'=> $names);
        $this->db->insert('testtable',$db_data);
*/          print_r($names);
        }   

            }
```

my action `<?php echo form_open_multipart('post/add') ?>`

and what ive got the error is this way

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

Line Number: 161
You did not select a file to upload.
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out? on how multiple uploads will do in codeigniter?? Any help is muchly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try with specific input name like that `$this->upload->do_upload('photo');`

Comment: yes i have a $this->upload->do_upload('photo'); code in it

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
class Imageupload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('imageupload_view', array('error' => ' ' ));
}
function doupload() {
    $name_array = array();
    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
    for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
    $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
    $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];   
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
        }
        $names= implode(',', $name_array);
 /*         $this->load->database();
        $db_data = array('id'=> NULL,
                         'name'=> $names);
    $this->db->insert('testtable',$db_data);
 */         print_r($names);
 }
 }
```

view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('imageupload/doupload');?>
<input name="userfile[]" id="userfile" type="file" multiple="" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
<?php echo form_close() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$files = $_FILES;
$cpt = count($_FILES['photo']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
{

    $_FILES['photo']['name']= $files['photo']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['photo']['type']= $files['photo']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']= $files['photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['photo']['error']= $files['photo']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['photo']['size']= $files['photo']['size'][$i];    
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        ....
        ....

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
}
```

Comment: where will i add this code?
print_r($fileObject)
below?

Comment: ive tried to add print_r then this is what it goes
Array ( [name] => samsung-galaxy-note-3-unboxing-india-photos-15.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6CA5.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 112069 )

Comment: and my input is 
<input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple="" />
and ive got errors on this name="photo[]"

Comment: except if i will only use name="photo" the print_r($fileObject ) will execute

Comment: why would you need **name="photo[]"**

Comment: cause i want to upload multiple images thats why im using name="photo[]"

Comment: I updated the code. See also this tutorial http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/uploading-multiple-files-images-in-codeigniter/

Comment: i just added it. it says undefined index tmp_name , error, size,type, name

Comment: i changed this $files['name'][$i] into $_FILES['name'][$i] and it says  undefined index  name

Comment: Dude, my bad! I change the code $fileObject['name'] not $files['name'][$i]

Comment: It says
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

Line Number: 161

Comment: Back where you started! :)) Must be something else.

Comment: do print_r($fileObject);

Comment: has an error it says
you did not select a file to upload 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

Line Number: 161

Comment: Help me a bit: do print_r($_FILES) before every thing and display the result here

Comment: i just changed the $this->upload->do_upload('photo[]'); the error is gone but the messages goes this way you did not select a file to upload

Comment: hi i just removed the $this->upload->do_upload('photo') and your code works now its print_r now.. but the for loop it cannot get on how many images

Comment: ok great! then how will i able to get all images inside the for loop? i tried to echo $cpt; exit; it displays 4 as what ive selected

Comment: But doesn't it upload any? Becouse it should as it is, unless u have some errors. do `echo $_FILES['photo']['error']= $files['photo']['error'][$i];` instead of `$_FILES['photo']['error']= $files['photo']['error'][$i];`

Comment: no, ***Echo*** this variable so you can se if there is any error on file uploads

Comment: yes ive tried print_r($_FILES['photo']['name']); exit; it will print only 1 name but when i do print_r($_FILES['photo']['type']); exit; it will print 3 types which is correct

Comment: yes i tried to print_r('$_FILES['photo']['error']); and it prints array of 3 with a value of 0 which is correct

Comment: but when i do print_r($_FILES['photo'['name']]); it only prints 1

Comment: Becouse it should be `print_r($_FILES['photo']['name']);`. Try `echo $this->upload->display_errors();` after the line `$this->upload->do_upload();`

Comment: yes i tried this one
print_r($_FILES['photo']['name']); sorry typo in above code

Comment: i tried
echo $this->upload->display_errors(); it says
the upload path does not appear to be valid

Comment: there we go! We're getting somewhere. What is the absolute path(C:\folder\etc\uploads) where you want to get these file uploaded?

Comment: echo `$config['upload_path']`, see if it returns the correct path, which it won't. then modify accordingly. And that would be it.

Comment: why in here?
$config['upload_path']???
my problem is i want to get all the files inside loop

Comment: dude, just do it, to see what path it returns.  `$config['upload_path']` sets the folder on the server where the files will end being uploaded. If that path  doesn't exist on your server or something else is wrong on the set path, it returns the error, you get: **upload path does not appear to be valid**.And _the files ARE inside the loop_, but the loop breaks on the first file, becouse it canno't write it on server. Does the folder where you want to upload even exist? If it does, is the path to it correct? If no, your files cannot be loaded, and the script exits with error.

Comment: so what does **echo $config['upload_path']** return? Is it the correct path?